# azure pipeline Script failed with exit code: 127

Tags: azure-devops, user-agent, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy an azure pipeline in devops with a local host agent pool and I get this error output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JadID.png)

I also share the structure of my yaml.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8PXl.png)

Does anyone know what could be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Consider pasting your YAML code here instead of sharing screenshots so people can easily copy and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if I use the following yml:

```
variables:
  - name: vmImageName
    value: 'ubuntu-20.04'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deployment
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'My Connection'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az --version
```

The result:
[image]

but in your case, we see windows path. pls check that you use correct yml, correct branch name to run....

[image]